# How to retain chinese/korean characters fetched from varchar value in java

Tags: java, varchar, oracle12c

I am using String variable to store value of varchar from a ResultSet. The problem is when I save this value in my application. It does'nt display the Chinese/Korean characters. I am sure the problem is not with rendering in my application because I am able to view those characters from a Clob object using the same code. What would be the preferred way to fetch varchar to retain unicode characters? Below is the small snippet to make to easy to explain the problem.

```
Result resultSet = statment.getResultSet();
while(resultSet.hasNext(){
String userName = commentRS.getString(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think that something was messed during the encoding translation from database's CLOB to Java's String then you can try to use this code to avoid it:

```
String userName = new String(commentRS.getBytes(3), "UTF-8");
```

The idea is to get pure stream of bytes from database and then create a String with desired encoding.

Comment: I am getting NPE on using getBytes()

Comment: I am having problem with varchar data. I am able to correctly use CLOB data

Comment: Sorry, I meant varchar instead of CLOB.
As for the problem it's strange that getBytes throws NPE. Maybe this issue is similar to what's described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168494/resultset-getstring-on-varchar2-column-returns-empty-string)
I'm not very familiar with Oracle database but as far as I remember varchar is actually the same thing as varchar2 there